# How to run a process in the background of an HoloLens application?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, async-await, hololens

Currently, my code can load and render an obj file from the hololens' local memory. However, during this process, the application is completely suspended, and this can take up to several seconds depending on the size and complexity of the mesh.
Since one might suspect that the application crashed during this time, I want to move the rendering to a background process and keep the main thread active.

#### Current behaviour:

While loading and rendering an obj-file the application is suspended for a few seconds.

#### Desired behaviour:

The loading and rendering of the mesh is calculated in a background process and the app remains active.

#### Code snippet:

```
public class FileExplorer: MonoBehaviour {
    private FileOpenPicker openPicker;

    public void OpenExplorer() {
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(() = >OpenFileAsync(), false);
        LoadModelFromFile();
    }

    private async void OpenFileAsync() {
        openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".obj");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null) {
            path = file.Path;
        }
    }

    public void LoadModelFromFile() {
        Mesh newMesh = Instantiate(GetComponent < ObjFileLoader > ().LoadModel(path)) as Mesh;
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

- i have stripped everything that i think is not necessary, if there are some problems i can add it to the existing code
- `LoadModel(path)` returns a Mesh
- i tried to make it similar to the async OpenFileAsync function, but that only led to several errors
- i have read about async ([Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html); [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but do not quite understand it
- maybe someone can hint me, what value i should `await`

If someone had a similar problem and could help me to solve this one or could give me a hint, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.

```cs
public async Task OpenExplorer() {
    UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async() => await OpenFileAsync(), false);
    await Task.Run(LoadModelFromFile);
}
```

My suggestion for you, though, is to read more on Async and Await because depending on your situation, the above code may not follow best practices and could be dangerous.

The main thing is that Async and Await is *not* about multi-threaded code. Async and Await are about using a single thread more efficiently. There are two main bottlenecks in code, IO, and CPU, and async await works well with IO bottlenecks because it can free up threads to work on other things while you wait for a disk operation or while you wait on a web request (which are not consuming any threads).

If you make a method async, but the only thing you are doing to make it async is kicking off a lot of long running code onto a different thread, it isn't that helpful unless the thread you are freeing up is the UI thread, but the only way you know that for sure is if you are on the UI thread.

So, only do `await Task.Run...` kind of stuff from a UI context when you need to free up the UI thread. Everywhere else, only label methods as async if they are purely IO related async like `File.ReadAsync` or others that do no consume any extra threads.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your detailed answer, I appreciate it very much. Following the advice, I will read more about Async and Await. In case it does not work as planned, I wanted to ask if there is another method I could try?

Comment: If you are consuming a lot of time on the UI thread about all you can do is run the long running code on a different thread. Async and await make it easy to handle because it automatically captures the UI context, so when your background task finishes it will automatically continue on the UI thread, but you can also communicate work done on a background thread using `ContinueWith` or with events.